# Using JSHint with Mocha and Chai

Tags: mocha.js, jshint, chai

I am running Mocha tests (with Chai as an assertion library).

At the moment JSHint fires a warning every time it encounters a line like this one:

> expect(err).to.be.null;

The reported problem is:

> Expected an identifier and instead saw 'null' (a reserved word).

Is there any relax option for JSHint to fix this issue?
At the moment the only solution I have only found is to include the special option at the beginning of the file:

> /*jshint -W024 */

The problem with that is that it needs to be included in every test file (and I would rather separate JSHint options from the code itself). I do not seem to have found much in [the options list](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually realized that I had an enforcing option enabled.

To fix it I only had to set:

> "es3": false

(Since it is the default, the same can be obtained removing the option completely)

Answer (score 5):

You can put the following settings:

```
{
  "expr": true,
  "es5": true
}
```

in a `.jshintrc` file at the top level of your test suite. I'm still on version 1.1.0 of jshint and thus need both settings but apparently version 2.0.0 and above has `es5` set to true by default. The `expr` setting is documented [here](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/#expr). There no longer a reference for `es5` probably because it is default and cannot be turned off. (Jshint 2.0.0 will raise an error if you try to set it manually.)

The way jshint operates when checking a file is by looking for a `.jshintrc` file in the same directory as your file. If not found, then it looks one level up. If not found there, then it looks one more level up, etc.